# Avoid right jump of elements with javascript and local variable when hiding vertical scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like to add left margin and right margin to the body to hide the width change when I hide the vertical scrollbar.

I have this code that finds the width of the vertical scrollbar:

```
    var $outer = $('<div>').css({visibility: 'hidden', width: 100, overflow: 'scroll'}).appendTo('body'),
    widthWithScroll = $('<div>').css({width: '100%'}).appendTo($outer).outerWidth();
    $outer.remove();
    var scrollbarwidth = 100 - widthWithScroll;
```

It gives the value "17" (in pixels) for IE11, Chrome 45, and Firefox 39 (desktop).

When I hide the vertical scrollbar, all elements, such as images, jump exactly 17 pixels to the right, which I want to hide.

I have tried:

```
    document.body.style.marginRight = scrollbarwidth + "px";

    $('body').css('margin-right', scrollbarwidth);

    $(body).css("marginRight", scrollbarwidth + "px");
```

The last one might be faulty in some way, since other parts of the function stops working when it's enabled. The two others don't seem to work either, as I don't see any margin changes.

EDIT 1: For easier understanding of how I am going to use it, I wanted to mention that it's supposed to trigger on a on scroll function, like this:

```
var check1 = false;

$(document).bind('scroll', function() {
    if(check1 === false && $(window).scrollTop() >= $('#divscrolltester').offset().top + $('#divscrolltester').outerHeight() - window.innerHeight) {

    check1 = true;

    unloadScrollBars();
    disableScroll();

    var $outer = $('<div>').css({visibility: 'hidden', width: 100, overflow: 'scroll'}).appendTo('body'),
    widthWithScroll = $('<div>').css({width: '100%'}).appendTo($outer).outerWidth();
    $outer.remove();
    var scrollbarwidth = 100 - widthWithScroll;

    //document.body.style.paddingRight = scrollbarwidth + "px"; Temporary disabled.
    //$('body').css('padding-right', scrollbarwidth); Temporary disabled.
    //$(body).css("marginRight", scrollbarwidth + "px"); Temporary disabled.

    setTimeout(function() {
    enableScroll();
    reloadScrollBars();

    //document.body.style.paddingLeft = scrollbarwidth + "px"; Temporary disabled.
    //$('body').css('padding-left', scrollbarwidth); Temporary disabled.
    //$(body).css("marginLeft", scrollbarwidth + "px"); Temporary disabled.

    }, 500);

   }   
});
```

EDIT 2:

Here is a Fiddle to show most of the js, html and css: https://jsfiddle.net/tfnwj7dj/10/.

I haven't added the change of css through code yet, as I'm still trying to solve the issue. Also, the scrolling and scrollbar are supposed to be re-enabled in a second, but there seems to be an error in there somewhere, sorry.

EDIT 3:

For your information at this moment, these lines work:

```
    document.body.style.paddingLeft = (scrollbarwidth) + "px";

    $('body').css('padding-left', scrollbarwidth);

    document.body.style.paddingRight = (scrollbarwidth) + "px";

    $('body').css('padding-right', scrollbarwidth);

    document.body.style.marginLeft = (scrollbarwidth) + "px";

    $('body').css('margin-left', scrollbarwidth);

    document.body.style.marginRight = (scrollbarwidth) + "px";

    $('body').css('margin-right', scrollbarwidth);
```

Maybe you have enough information to solve it, if you have the same issue, but unfortunately, this wasn't enough for me. It might be important info to know that I have my content centered with a width / max-width of just 500px, and that I don't actually have a body class. Maybe on designs with width="100%", or elements with absolute positioning, the lines might be enough.

Both javascript and jquery solutions are welcomed.

EDIT 4:

I finally solved it for my own circumstances - feel free to read the answer below. It works for preventing elements to jump when hiding the vertical scrollbar, and with some tinkering, it could probably do for a body class, or other situations.

Comment: Have you tried `document.getElementById("myDiv").style.marginLeft = (scrollbarwidth) + "px"; `

Comment: Try padding instead (margin will have an 'inward' effect on `body`), it works... http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EVZVdV

Comment: @Shikkediel Thanks, I'll try padding instead. I'm trying to use `$('body').css('padding-right', scrollbarwidth);` but the elements still jump to the right...

Comment: We may need a bit more insight in the style that was set on the elements then... Of course you could also circumvent the jump altogether : http://tinyurl.com/pf6uxch.

Comment: @Shikkediel I tried to make a fiddle which is similar to what I have now: https://jsfiddle.net/tfnwj7dj/. I can try that fix that you mentioned, but how does it behave in mobile devices?

Comment: That blog's solution should be fine for all devices, the only thing is to keep about 20 pixels on the right free of content (mostly for desktop with a physical scrollbar). This may mess with exact alignment of the page a bit but that's the trade off. Let me have a good look at that fiddle though.

Comment: Removed the answer I posted but here's the fiddle just in case you'd like to use the debouncing function for calculating the scrollbar width : https://jsfiddle.net/z6mr9hca/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it - I'd like to clarify that my css actually don't contain a body class, and that I just centered all elements with a width / max-width of 500px and margin-left/right auto.

For my and other, similar cases, here is the answer:

```
    /* First 5 lines for finding the scrollbar width. */
    var $outer = $('<div>').css({visibility: 'hidden', width: 100, overflow: 'scroll'}).appendTo('body'),
    widthWithScroll = $('<div>').css({width: '100%'}).appendTo($outer).outerWidth();
    $outer.remove();
    var scrollbarwidth = 100 - widthWithScroll;
    var scrollbarwidthadjustment = scrollbarwidth / 2; /* For centered elements, divide the scrollbar width by 2. */

    var element = document.getElementById('element');
    element.style.right = (scrollbarwidthadjustment) + "px";
```

And when you re-enable the vertical scrollbar, simply add:

```
    element.style.right = "0px";
```

Also, the element must have a css position stated, otherwise it won't trigger. Here is an example of a css style that works:

```
.examplestyle {
   color: white;
   position: relative;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   max-width: 100%;
   display: block;
```

}

EDIT 1:

To prevent some unsightly css errors on mobile devices, add these lines:

```
    /* ... */
   var scrollbarwidthadjustment = scrollbarwidth / 2;

   var windowWidth  = $(window).width(); /* Get current window width on click/scroll etc. */
   var window1 = windowWidth + scrollbarwidth; /* Window width + scrollbar width. */

   var element = document.getElementById('element');
    if(window1 >= widthofelement) {element.style.right = (scrollbarwidthadjustment) + "px";}
      else {}
```

EDIT 2:

Fix for image resized smaller than its original size:

```
    var offsetwidth = element.offsetWidth;
    var widthadjustment = offsetwidth - scrollbarwidth; /* Get full width of image when scrollbar hidden, and then remove the scrollbar width. */

    if(window1 < widthofelement && scrollbarwidth > 0) {
      element.style.width = widthadjustment + "px";
      element.style.right = (scrollbarwidthadjustment) + "px";
    }
```

And then this code when showing the Y-scrollbar again:

```
    if(window1 < widthofelement && scrollbarwidth > 0) {
      element.style.width = "OriginalSizepx";
      element.style.right = "0px";
    }
```

If you want to use every edit that I have added, here is the full code:

```
    /* First 5 lines for finding the scrollbar width. */
    var $outer = $('<div>').css({visibility: 'hidden', width: 100, overflow: 'scroll'}).appendTo('body'),
    widthWithScroll = $('<div>').css({width: '100%'}).appendTo($outer).outerWidth();
    $outer.remove();
    var scrollbarwidth = 100 - widthWithScroll;
    var scrollbarwidthadjustment = scrollbarwidth / 2; /* For centered elements, divide the scrollbar width by 2. */

    var element = document.getElementById('element'); /* Put element ID into a variable for easier use, and consecutive uses without re-identifying it. */

    var window1 = windowWidth + scrollbarwidth; /* Window width + scrollbar width. */
    var offsetwidth = element.offsetWidth; /* Get exact element size in current window. Shows shown dimensions when the window is resized. */
    var widthadjustment = offsetwidth - scrollbarwidth; /* Get full width of image when scrollbar hidden, and then remove the scrollbar width. */

    if(window1 >= widthofelement) {element.style.right = (scrollbarwidthadjustment) + "px";} /* If current window is equal to or greater than element width... */
    if(window1 < widthofelement && scrollbarwidth > 0) { /* If current windows is smaller than the element width, and the window has a scrollbar greater than 0 pixels in width. */
      element.style.width = widthadjustment + "px";
      element.style.right = (scrollbarwidthadjustment) + "px";
    }

    /* When re-enabling the Y-scrollbar again; */

    if(window1 >= widthofelement) {element.style.right = "0px";}

    if(window1 < widthofelement && scrollbarwidth > 0) {
      element.style.width = "OriginalSizepx";
      element.style.right = "0px";
    }
```

For further clarification, this code will prevent elements from jumping to the right when you hide the vertical scrollbar.

Answer (score 1):

Is your scrollbarwidth integer? Try this

```
var scrollbarwidth = 100;
$('body').css('margin-right', scrollbarwidth);
```

Maybe you have wrong value at scrollbarwidth ? In my ff this code works.

Comment: Hm, I tried to disable my other scrollwidth code with /* */, and used exactly your code, but I don't see any changes when I call the function.

I have added my test function (on scroll) to my question.

@ErmineSoft

Comment: @EmineSoft Actually, on further testing, your code works. It's just that on my current settings, it still didn't fix my issue. My content is centered with a max-width of 500px.

Answer (score 0):

`padding` is your answer, as Shikkediel said. Just change `margin` to that and it'll work.

The items move because you change the default `margin` body has, so the whole body moves to the left (in case we are modifying `margin-right`).

If you remove the scroll bar, the default `margin` will go right behind it, and then you need to "buffer" the rest, left of the margin, and that's what `padding` does.

I really enjoy working with the Inspecting tool Chrome supplies (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>) and then in the `Styles` tab on the right scorll down until you see the measurements. It really helps understand the CSS box model.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add 'px' here..

```
$('body').css('margin-right', scrollbarwidth+'px')??
```

Just nowI tried in w3schools. If you add 'px' to above syntax, it is working for me.